# Clarification on labelled graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I am ready Bondy and Murthy's *Graph Theory*:

> [image]

And here is the Figure $1.10$:

> [image]

I don't understand what are these three labelled graphs for $P_3$, in the figure, I see $4$ different graphs: $0$ edge, $1$ edge, $2$ edges, $3$ edges. Changing the labelling of the vertices would make three different graphs only if the number of edges is $1$ or $2$, isn't it?

Comment: There are $4$ different **unlabelled** graphs on $3$ vertices: $0$ edges, $1$ edge, $2$ edges, $3$ edges. The $8$ different **labelled** graphs on $3$ vertices are shown in the figure. The $3$ different **labelled** graphs on $P_3$ are shown in the first three diagrams on the second row. Do you know what $P_3$ is?

Comment: @bof Oh, yes. A path must take all the vertices. I confused $P_3$ with arbitrary simple graphs on $3$ vertices. I know it now.